# Populate separate arrays in iPhone from data in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone

In one of my applications I have a requirement to fetch data from an `NSMutableArray` and store the data which we got in separate arrays in iPhone. Please provide a solution for me. How do I accomplish this?

Requirements are listed below:

1. Actually total projects are available in one array (this I got from server).
2. Total number of filters available in another array (this also I got from server).
3. Based on each filter (each filter is linked with few projects) I have to fetch projects from projects array.
4. I am able to fetch projects related to separate filter,  but the problem is that after fetching the projects I have to store those projects in separate new arrays related to each filter (means here I have to create new array in runtime).

   It is here that I am having trouble.  How do I create arrays dynamically at runtime instead of declaring them in advance?  Because the filters count will vary at any point of time at server side, I cannot predict in advance how many arrays I need.

I’m following this approach, but this is the issue I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

Create one Mutable Dictionary in which add the project with respective filter and add that object in new NSMutable array.This you will each different project with respective filter.You can fetch the projects form respective Key for project.